# React Smart and Dumb Components

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Have been working on React and would like to know, best practices for seperating smart and dumb componenents. Example below Parent controls state, but i have put button ui in render, should these go into child and implemented back to parent via callback or is that overkill? thoughts..here is my code

```
class Child extends React.Component { 
  constructor(props){
  super(props);
  }
  render() {
  return (
     <div><p>I said {this.props.greeting} {this.props.count} times</p>    
    </div>
    );
  }
}

class Parent extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = { 
      count: 0,
      greeting: "Hello"
    };
  }

  sayHello() {
    this.setState((prevState, props) => {
    return { 
      count: prevState.count + 1,
          greeting: "Hello"
           }
    }                   
  )};
    sayGoodBye() {
    this.setState((prevState, props) => {    
    return {       
      count: this.count = 1,
      greeting: "Goodbye"
           }
    }                   
  )};



  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => this.sayHello() }>Say Hello</button>
        <button onClick={() => this.sayGoodBye() }>Say Goodbye</button>
      <Child count={this.state.count} greeting={this.state.greeting} />
        </div>
    )

  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Parent />, document.getElementById('app'));
```

Comment: Could this be perhaps more suitable for [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: More a best practice question than a code review, but i will put it up there also for any suggestions

Answer (score 1):

I think the separation in this case is good. The buttons are directly involved with the state of Parent so creating a child just for them will be an overkill. In general the "dump" components are only about visually showing data/state. Sometimes they contain elements like buttons but the only one thing that they do is to notify the outside world that **X** thing happened.

Also the Child could be a stateless function:

```
const Child = ({ greeting, count }) => (
  <div>
    <p>I said { greeting } { count } times</p>
  </div>
);
```

You could try making a component to be just a function. If you can't then it is probably not as dump as you think it is :)

Comment: It's correct I think. Also the Child component could be really a stateless function. Check out my answer above.